# Unable to fetch query parameter in NextJS

Tags: api, redirect, next.js, routes, url-parameters

I have an API route `/api/form`

```js
// ./pages/api/form.js
import Router from 'next/router';
...
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    ...
    res.redirect(307, '/summary?username=username');
    Router.push({
        pathname: '/summary',
        query: {
            username: username
        }
    });
}
```

```js
// ./pages/summary.js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
export default function Summary() {
    const router = useRouter();
    console.log(router.query);  // undefined
}
```

I am not able to fetch the query param. Also, if change the order of `Router.push` and `res.redirect`, I still stay on the `/api/form` route

I also tried using `useRouter().push` as per the documentation. Still, I stay in the `/api/form` route.

How to get the query param?

Comment: You can't use `Router.push` on the server-side. Make a request from the client to `/api/form` then handle the routing based on the response you get from the API.

Comment: @juliomalves Actually, the requirement is that, I want to post from the api route to a page. The page must not load until the query is fetched from this api route. `getServerSideProps()` is not working. So, what I did is, I saved everything that is required to a file and then, this file is uniquely identified by the username and hence if I can get the username from the query route, I can directly render the page from this file without posting anything from this api. I am not able to post from api to a page.

Comment: _"I want to post from the api route to a page"_ - You can't do that. As you mentioned, you should be using `getServerSideProps` for this. Can you show us what you attempted with `getServerSideProps`?

Answer (score 2):

`next/router` allows you to do client-side transitions: https://vercel.fyi/next-router-client-side

For your use case I suggest putting the `router.push` event inside your form submit event, something like this:

```
<form
  onSubmit={() => {
    fetch(`/api/form`, {
      ...
    }).then((res) => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        router.push({
          pathname: '/summary',
          query: {
            username: username
          }
        })
      }
    )
  }
}
>
...
</form>
```